# How to Allow Use of Larger Database Sizes in MySQL Docker Container on MacOS

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm moving my grails application + MySQL database into docker containers through the use of docker-compose on my MacOS host machine. I have everything able to run successfully, but I need to import a large database file (16GB). Initially everything is importing fine, but after a bit I start getting errors that `grails_mysql  | 2021-08-02 21:55:16 1 [ERROR] mysqld: The table 'users' is full`. A bit after getting a bunch of those errors, it quits out with the below error:

```
grails_mysql  | 2021-08-02 21:55:16 7fc7761017002021-08-02 21:55:16 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failure of system call pwrite(). Operating system error number is 28.
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'.
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
grails_mysql  | 2021-08-02 21:55:16 1 [ERROR] mysqld: The table 'tabe_name' is full
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: Fatal error (Out of disk space) in rollback.
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: Out of tablespace.
grails_mysql  | InnoDB: Consider increasing your tablespace.
```

I assumed this means I needed to give docker more disk space, so I opened the docker GUI and went to the advanced settings and set `Disk Image Size` to 128GB, since that's the only value in the settings related to disk space. However, when I try to run the container at all after making that change, I get this error: `no space left on device: unknown`.

Then after deleting the containers and trying again, same thing happened, so I don't think that `Disk Image Size` value was the issue. How can I expand the disk space given to the database? (I have plenty of disk space on my host machine, so that's not the issue).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  grails:
    image: ibbrussell/grails:2.3.11
    command: run-app
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
      - ~/.gradle:/root/.gradle
      - ~/.grails:/root/.grails
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" #Grails default port
      - "5005:5005" #Grails debug port
    depends_on:
      - db
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4G
        reservations:
          memory: 4G
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: grails_mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: grails
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/mysql_container:/var/lib/mysql
```

If it helps at all, this happens exactly when I submit 1GB of data into the database, so it seems like a value is defaulted to 1GB when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Also try to raise Memory. I had the same problem. Message within the container talks about disk space, but in the end it needed just more internal memory.

Comment: @BertC Tried giving it more memory, same error in the same time. So I don't think it helped sadly.

Comment: check the docker settings to make sure it's set to allocate the entire volume size at once and not as the volume size increases.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/increase-container-volume-disk-size/1652/2 this might help. looks like you have to set it to change the 'default' size.

Comment: @Caperneoignis Nothing I found in this helped sadly. It's all using `devicemapper` when I have to use `overlay2` because I'm on macOS

Comment: use docker exec -it <containerID> bash and check output of this command - $df -h

Comment: @yourknightmares yea, not sure where the problem lies. I know Mac has some funny ways of doing hard drive formatting so it may lay with the fact you are requesting such a big size for a volume? Have you tried this same move in Linux? At least to narrow down it isn't a formatting issue on the host machine? Just to trouble shoot.

Comment: I mean, to make sure it isn't the type of hard drive format that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to clean up some extra unused images and containers and try again you can use

`docker system prune`

be-careful with this command because it removes all stoped containers and unused images. if you are not sure how to use this just remove them by hand

`docker images`

`docker rmi <containerid>`

after clean up just restart your docker app and start your container log into you container by

`docker exec -it <containerID> bash`

check out how much memory is available by

`df -h`

Answer (score 0):

If this does not get resolved the 'right way' (by increasing the Docker disk allocation), consider the following:

Set up a "volume" so that the MySQL (inside Docker) will reach outside for its disk space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Docker only allocated a small part of the 128G disk you set but not all of it. The real disk size can be expanded when it's needed.

You may need check your Mac host's real disk capacity. It's probably less than 16Gb.
If it is, you can login the host and expand the disk space.

[Increase container volume(disk) size](https://forums.docker.com/t/increase-container-volume-disk-size/1652)